# Combining values from one query with another by using values from first in where clause of second

Tags: sql, subquery

This is going to be complicated to explain but hope you get what i'm trying to accomplish.

I have a transposed dataset that looks something like follows:

```
STATION    | MEDIA   | TEMPERATURE | 

station 1  | Water   | 50

station 1  | acid    | 20
```

This is obtained by using a spesific eventID in the where clause. This can return up to 10 rows per id

I now have a list of EventIDs that i get by running a different query

I want to pass this list to the first query and have a resultant set that looks as follows:

```
EventID  |STATION    | MEDIA   | TEMPERATURE | 

1        |station 1  | Water   | 50          |

1        |station 1  | acid    | 20          |  

2        |station 1  | Water   | 66          |

2        |station 1  | acid    | 35          |
```

I have tried procedural but this takes very long when having a lot of ids ( can be 50 or more)
Each ID needs to be passed separately because I'm grouping to do the temp etc calculations before transposing the table. 
Is there a set based way of doing this where i'm not looping through every ID row basically?

Comment: updated so to reflect that first column is actaually the eventid that im passing into the first query. Not the row number etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a `join` query.  In this case, you are using `join` to filter the results:

```
select d.*
from dataset1 d join
     differentquery q
     on d.station = q.station;
```

Getting the `id` column at the beginning depends on the database.  A typical method is:

```
select row_number() over (partition by station order by station) as id, d.*
from dataset1 d join
     differentquery q
     on d.station = q.station;
```

Answer (score 0):

So rather then executing the first query with, say, `WHERE id = 1`, you want to have something like `WHERE id IN (ids from second query)`. You can do just that:

```
select ... -- first query here
where id in
(
  select id -- second query here 
  from ...
);
```

Comment: if use in ... it will summ al the different stations temp etc together instead of having it as individual temps per event.

Comment: Isn't that just a matter of grouping? So far you group by STATION + MEDIA, now you must group by EventID + STATION + MEDIA. If this  doesn't solve it, then re-write your joins such as that you don't join single records of a table and aggregate afterwords, but aggregate first and join with that derived table.

Comment: The problem is that the ID, Media are actually values in the same column, So i ran a query to first get the ids. Then use those ids to get all the events that belong together and the calculate the average temp for the different medias for that ID

Comment: Sorry, I'd have to see the query to be able to tell you how to handle this. Sometimes when joining first and aggregating later you count or sum values more than once. E.g. You join tables of products, dealers and sales and want to know how many dealers and how many sales per product. With a product with 2 dealers and 3 sales of 10, 20 and 40 pieces you get COUNT(\*) = 6 and SUM(pieces) = 140, but you need COUNT(distinct dealer.id) = 2 and SUM(pieces) / COUNT(distinct dealer.id) = 70. This looks clumsy and can sometimes be circumvented by using derived tables or subqueries in the result part.

Comment: Example for a derived table: `JOIN (SELECT id_product, COUNT(*) as count_dealers FROM ProductDealers GROUP BY id_product) agg_dealers ON p.id = agg_dealers.id_product` Example for a sub-query in the select list: `SELECT p.id , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProductDealers pd WHERE pd.id_product = p.id) FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

I don't rely understand what you want but if you want rows number that's the method

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY m_product_id) AS Rw,
      station as st,
      media as med,
      tempiratue as tmp
    FROM YourTable
```

if you want a row number by a SELECT

```
SELECT (Select ID from YourTable Where   --YourCountraint,
      station as st,
      media as med,
      tempiratue as tmp
    FROM YourTable
```

if its not just tell me what rely you want and i will update my response

Comment: updated my question to reflect that the first column is actually the eventid that i'm passing to the first query not row number. Thanks